# Past perfect in stories

Tags: past-perfect, quotations

I read the news about Hefner's death and want to understand why past perfect used in the sentence I've marked in bold and caps down below:

> "But others pointed out that while Hefner launched his brand and his lifestyle off the back of that first Playboy issue in December 1953, Monroe was embarrassed by the shoot that appeared in it - and feared for her future career. She **HAD AGREED** to pose nude as a young woman, short on acting work and desperate for money. She received $50 in modeling fees."

Comment: I suppose the sense of the passage is that Marilyn Monroe was embarrassed after the magazine came out, even though she _had earlier_ agreed to pose in the nude for it.

Comment: Yes, Kate, and 259543, if the passage merely said *she agreed*, only broad context would indicate that her agreeing to pose nude was a matter wholly in the past… the verb tense wouldn't do that.

In this particular instance, that danger might be very slight; in others, it could be very confusing.